# How to combine these two javascript/jquery scripts

Tags: javascript

I have an id #navigation li a and a class .menu-description . I want to change text color of the class .menu-description when hovered on #navigation li a

My jquery so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li a').mouseover(function() {

  //Check if element with class exists, if so change it to new
           if ($('div.menu-description').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-description').removeClass('menu-description').addClass('menu-descriptionnew');
           //Check if element with class 'menu-descriptionnew' exists, if so change it to 'menu-description'
           else if ($('div.menu-descriptionnew').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-descriptionnew').removeClass('menu-descriptionnew').addClass('menu-description');
                });
});
</script>
```

second script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-description').hover( function(){

        $(this).css('color', '#EEEEEE');

    },
    function(){

        $(this).css('color', '#000000');

    });

});
</script>
```

How to combine these to in order to reach for my wanted result?

Comment: It might be easier to explain your problem if you create a mock-up using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: +1 and at least post your HTML code which goes with it, because if you build your html properly, what you seem to want to achieve could be done with pure CSS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li a').mouseover(function() {

  //Check if element with class exists, if so change it to new
           if ($('div.menu-description').length != 0)
                colorA();
           //Check if element with class 'menu-descriptionnew' exists, if so change it to 'menu-description'
           else if ($('div.menu-descriptionnew').length != 0)
                $colorB();
                });
});

function colorA()
{
   $(this).css('color', '#EEEEEE');
}

function colorB(){
   $(this).css('color', '#000000');
}

$('.menu-description').hover(colorA,colorB);
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li a').mouseover(function() {

  //Check if element with class exists, if so change it to new
           if ($('div.menu-description').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-description').removeClass('menu-description').addClass('menu-descriptionnew');
           //Check if element with class 'menu-descriptionnew' exists, if so change it to 'menu-description'
           else if ($('div.menu-descriptionnew').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-descriptionnew').removeClass('menu-descriptionnew').addClass('menu-description');
                });

    $('.menu-description').hover( function(){

        $(this).css('color', '#EEEEEE');

    },
    function(){

        $(this).css('color', '#000000');

    });

});
```